# Model binding error when implementing post-get-redirect pattern with temp data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core 2.2 and trying to implement the pattern outlined at [POST-REDIRECT-GET using TempData in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/). I have two actions as follows:

```
[ImportModelState]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(int id, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    // ...
    return this.View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ExportModelState]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(int id, MyModel model, CancellationToken ct)
{
    // ...
}
```

After accessing the `get` view, entering the form details and submitting, I set a break point in the `post` action to view the bound model data for the `MyModel` parameter and I see an array for a boolean `Replace` field which backs a checkbox in the views form:[image: model state] However the `Replace` field works and if the model state is valid, everything succeeds for both of the form checkbox states.

If the form is invalid and I serialize the modelstate to tempdata and merge it on a redirect to the `get` action, I get an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: The parameter conversion from type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Boolean' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.`

Why does the model binder create an array for the boolean field (is this due to the semantics for forms and check boxes?) which works on the `post` action, but the same data fails to bind against the same model type when repopulating the view?

The serialization to temp data uses the following logic:

```
var errorList = modelState
    .Select(kvp => new ModelStateTransferValue
    {
        Key = kvp.Key,
        AttemptedValue = kvp.Value.AttemptedValue,
        RawValue = kvp.Value.RawValue,
        ErrorMessages = kvp.Value.Errors
            .Select(p => p.ErrorMessage)
            .ToList(),
    });
```

The deserialization and merging uses the following logic:

```
var errorList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ModelStateTransferValue>>(serialized);
var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();

foreach (var item in errorList)
{
    modelState.SetModelValue(item.Key, item.RawValue, item.AttemptedValue);
    foreach (var error in item.ErrorMessages)
    {
        modelState.AddModelError(item.Key, error);
    }
}

filterContext.ModelState.Merge(modelState);
```

Comment: Can you show us how you coded the serialization of the `ModelState` to `TempData`?

Comment: No problem, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't actually following post-redirect-get. The redirect happens *on success*. If there's validation errors, you just return the view again. No need to persist anything in `TempData`. Even the author of the linked article points out:

> As PRG is primarily intended to prevent double form submissions, it does not necessarily follow that you should REDIRECT a user if the form is invalid. In that case, the request should not be modifying state, and so it is valid to submit the form again.

Where he goes astray is in the whole use `TempData` for invalid submissions and still redirect thing. That's just patently wrong, and I actually find it a little surprising that that advice is coming from Andrew Lock. I've referenced his articles quite often, but apparently never noticed this one.

In software development, there's an unspoken golden rule: don't be a unicorn. Doing things differently than virtually every other developer on the planet doesn't make you unique and special; it makes you an idiot.

**UPDATE**

Wow. Just reading through the comments and came across one from Andrew where he says:

> Having said that, I haven't actually personally used this approach - as you say it adds a lot of complexity

That's a done deal right there. I mean it's an interesting thought experiment, but if it's not good enough for the guy who wrote it, it's not good enough for anyone else either.

All this does is get rid of the "Confirm form resubmission" dialog when a user refreshes a page that was submitted with invalid data. The case where the post is successful is already covered by PRG in general. Given the complexity, and all the extra requests, it's just not even remotely worth it for something that might not even ever happen. Personally, I've found users to be *afraid* to refresh the page, fearing that they'll have to re-enter all the fields again (which ironically this solution would actually *cause*, whereas they'd have been just fine refreshing otherwise).

Comment: I am not sure I agree, if you don't redirect on every response from the post action, you can not refresh the page without re-posting. By always redirecting, when you encounter a form error and are then redirected to a view with your data and model errors, you can refresh and start from scratch.

Comment: Again, not only will most users *not* refresh, even if they did, their expectation would be for the data to remain, not be cleared. This is an atypical, and I would go so far as to say anti-pattern, approach, that the author of the article you're referencing isn't even using himself. This is a KISS moment. Choose wisely.